# How to increase the font size of year drop-down of datepicker

Tags: css, primefaces

i am trying to increase the size of month and year picker and also trying to increase size of font using css 
[image]

want to increase font of this year picker dropdown.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the following CSS class to control the `width` and `font-size` of both the drop-down(s) of `p:calendar`:

```
.ui-datepicker .ui-datepicker-title select {
    width: XX%;
    font-size: XXpx;
}
```

Where `XX` is your desired value while default value for `width` is `49%` and `font-size` is `1em`. Try with values greater than the defaults.

While, if you want to play with individual drop-down, then there is also a specific class applied over each drop-down as `ui-datepicker-month` and `ui-datepicker-year`.

You can use those as following:

```
.ui-datepicker select.ui-datepicker-month {
    /* Your CSS declaration for month drop-down */
}

.ui-datepicker select.ui-datepicker-year {
    /* Your CSS declaration for year drop-down */
}
```

Comment: tried but it will not increase font size of year in dropdown. Is it possible to change color of dropdown of year

Comment: Are you trying greater values than the default values? If so, you can `!important` to force override your value.

Comment: yes i tried  .ui-datepicker select.ui-datepicker-month {
    font-size: 36px !important;
}

Comment: Yes you can by using `background-color: #4B4E4F;` property for background color of the drop-down and `color: #E3E3E3;` for font color.

Comment: Okay, as I earlier said that, if you want apply same `font-size` value on both the drop-downs, use this (`.ui-datepicker .ui-datepicker-title select`) class. While, you are using specific class for month drop-down, how would that apply on year? Use this (`.ui-datepicker select.ui-datepicker-year`) class for year drop-down, if you want to use separated styles.

Comment: i tried both but no changes in dropdown it will change the title like month-oct

Comment: i tried both but none changes in dropdown it changes title of dropdown like oct will display in increased size

Comment: Try this: `.ui-datepicker .ui-datepicker-title select { font-size: 36px !important; }`

Comment: I have verified that from the showcase and its working. I am not sure, what problem are you facing.

Comment: it will chage month title not the dropdown item

Comment: it works on chrome browser not on firefox. thanks @Parkash Kumar

Comment: You might be facing cache problem in firefox then. :p Clear the browser cache and re-verify.